# How to install/import AndroidJunitRunner

Tags: android, junit, android-gradle-plugin

Following instructions at https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSetupInstructions I added the lines

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
```

to my gradle build file, and

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

The aar files are available in

```
/{sdk_home}/extras/android/m2repository
```

Apparently, that doesn't mean that gradle can now find them. How do I tell gradle to look for the files there, or how do I create the dependency? Putting the aar files in my libs dir and importing them from there doesn't work. Doesn't work for aar files in general.

This is my gradle build file:

```
repositories {
mavenCentral() // this or jcenter() required for testing-support-lib dependencies
mavenLocal()
}

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.loqli.android"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 22
    multiDexEnabled = true

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
}

   sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        }
        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/test/res']
        }
    }

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4096M"
}

}

dependencies {

wearApp project(':wear')

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'

compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs/roboguice', include: ['*.jar'])

//androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
}
```

edit: updated gradle build file

Comment: "that doesn't mean that gradle can now find them" -- how have you determined this? If you are using the Gradle for Android plugins (e.g., `com.android.application`), they should automatically know how to find your Android Repository installed from the SDK Manager. So, what are your specific symptoms?

Comment: AndroidJUnitRunner "can't be resolved".

Comment: Where is "can't be resolved" appearing? If you are using Android Studio, and you are seeing this when trying to run the tests from a run configuration you set up for them, click on the Build Variants view (by default docked on the left) and ensure that your "Test Artifact" is "Android Instrumentation Tests".

Comment: I did. AndroidJUnitRunner text is red, when I hover over it it says "Cannot resolve symbol AndroidJUnitRunner"

Comment: I don't know that it matters, but try moving your `dependencies` closure before the `android` closure. Here is a sample project where I am pulling in `rules:0.3` and successfully can use `AndroidJUnitRunner`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Testing/JUnit4

Comment: I put the aar files in my local maven repository. I changed "test artifact" back to "Unit Tests" after AS had made my test sources invisible. Then I changed "androidTestCompile" to "compile". Then the AndroidJunitRunner was no longer an "unknown symbol". Strange thing is, I changed "compile" back to "androidTestCompile", and it still works. I do see AS fumbling with my source dir structure as in the "Android" view. Also, adding "mavenCentral" as a repository helped. 
Mark, can you put your last comment in as an Answer?

Comment: AndroidJUnitRunner can't be resolved in the "test" folder, you have to move it to androidTest